# equivalent of unix "which" for exec-path?

Tags: tramp, exec-path

I am trying to debug some bizarre issues with my exec-path settings.

When I debug PATH in shell, the key tool is "which", which tells me the absolute path we resolve for a given binary, i.e.

```
(701) % which ifconfig
/sbin/ifconfig
```

Is there some equivalent to tell me, for example, what binary Tramp will get when it asks to execute "ssh"?

Answer (score 8):

You can attempt locating an executable in `exec-path` with `executable-find`:

```
(executable-find "ls") ;=> "/usr/bin/ls"
(executable-find "sl") ;=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Tramp provides a debugging buffer, usually `*debug tramp...*` that provides a lot of information. For example...

```
;; GNU Emacs: 24.4.51.2 Tramp: 2.2.9-24.4 -*- mode: outline; -*-
17:54:29.340451 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Opening connection for schwern.net using scp...
17:54:29.369182 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Sending command `exec ssh   -o ControlPath=/var/folders/0b/7xp2lxbd7yl0tcpms06fr3d40000gn/T/tramp.40010Dqz.%r@%h:%p -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=no -e none schwern.net'
```

You can see, it's running `exec ssh` which will pick up the normal `ssh` from your `PATH`. If you want to be sure you can run `M-x shell` and check `which ssh` or [use the commands in @wasamasa's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29578/14352).

What tramp will use to login is controlled by the `tramp-login-program` argument to the particular method in the `tramp-methods` variable. For example, here's the ssh method.

```
 ("ssh"
  (tramp-login-program "ssh")
  (tramp-login-args
   (("-l" "%u")
    ("-p" "%p")
    ("%c")
    ("-e" "none")
    ("%h")))
  (tramp-async-args
   (("-q")))
  (tramp-remote-shell "/bin/sh")
  (tramp-remote-shell-args
   ("-c"))
  (tramp-gw-args
   (("-o" "GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null")
    ("-o" "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null")
    ("-o" "StrictHostKeyChecking=no")))
  (tramp-default-port 22))
```